# Missing slide out div after backing to the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reload

I made 'animated' slide out menu with social media icons that I added to the page which I made by followin the tutorial from Udemy. It slides out on mouseenter() and slides back on mouseeleave(). I used animate() function.

Problem is when I click on any of the icons that lead me to another website and when I click back on my browser or my mouse buttom, my page loads but the menu is missing. I have to reload the page for menu to show up again. Is there any way to fix it so it shows automatically without reloading the page?

Thanks a lot.

Page loaded:
[image]

Menu open on mouseenter():
[image]

Wole menu missing after backing from facebook or any other:
[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#follow').mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).animate({
                left: "+=49px"
            }, 50);
        });
        $('#follow').mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).animate({
                left: "-=49px"
            }, 50);
        });
        $('#follow').click(function() {
            $(this).animate({
                left: "-=49px"
            }, 0);
        });

    });
```

```css
#follow {
  position                   : fixed;
  left                       : -50px;
  width                      : 70px;
  float                      : left;
  border-radius              : 0px;
  border-top-right-radius    : 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius : 15px;
  background-color           : #353535;
}

#follow #follow_id {
  padding-top : 15px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="final-example">

    <div id="follow">
      <ul id="follow_id">
        <li class=""><a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="img/facebook-logo-button.png" alt="facebook"/></a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="https://twitter.com/?lang=en"><img src="img/twitter-logo-button.png" alt="twitter"/></a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img src="img/instagram-logo.png" alt="instagram"/></a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
```

The snippet looks bad beacuse the pictures are missing and the alt is showing which I gotta fix, but the problem is when I click lets say facebook icon, it loads me facebook site, then if I press back button on my browser it gets me back to my page but that entire sliding menu is missing, it doesn't even load at all on my page. I have to click reload on my broswer for that menu to show up at all and only then I can use it.

Comment: Do you mean you want the image menu to already be shown if you opened the menu?

I would set a cookie with a flag with menu open and then just read in the flag when the page loads.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: A site or a snippet would be great. Also, when you say you have to reload the page, do you mean the entire div isn't being rendered when you hit back?

Comment: I added the snippet to show the code for my menu, sorry for that alt showing that I gotta fix. @ADarnal

Comment: And yes entire menu doesn't render @k2snowman69

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used your code in demo and it is working fine. I haven't seen any issue.

Please check this one.

https://output.jsbin.com/muluyu/1

If this dosen't work for you then it will be a browser related issue. Different browsers load the page differently when using the back button. Sometimes they cache the page and sometimes they reload the page. I believe still others only partially reload the page.

So for mozilla firefox back button won't refresh the page most of the time. because of that the #follow is going left -90px and so on adding -49 everytime. So add this line.

```
$('#follow').css('left', '-50px');
```

After document.ready(function () { ..

Final JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#follow').css('left', '-50px');
    $('#follow').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            left: "+=49px"
        }, 50);
    });
    $('#follow').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            left: "-=49px"
        }, 50);
    });
    $('#follow').click(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            left: "-=49px"
        }, 0);
    });

});
```

It will work for sure.

Demo : https://output.jsbin.com/muluyu/2

Comment: I saw it and it works perfectly in that demo, int the first demo menu was barely visible after 1st visit to facebook and backing. But I still have the  problem on my page. I guess then maybe I did something wrong elsewhere.. @KrishCdbry

Comment: Did you added this line : $('#follow').css('left', '-50px');  becuase I tried you code in firefox and the same issue I faced like you then I found it is due to the left value so I added that line and it started working.

Comment: Yes I did, and the same problem again. And even the second demo is not working anymore, great. I guess it maybe since it moves -49 px on click it automatically passes the point where the link was clicked so it executes the mouseleave() too. But if I delete that click() part of jquery animation and when I click the link and come back the menu stays open so it is another problem. I appreciate your help but this just doesn't want to work for me haha.

Comment: Cool buddy ! Try hard with smile you will be able to solve it :) Cheers

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it on chrome and both demo and my page work fine. Probably because it reloads the page automatically on back button press. I think I'll just have to find a way to reload the page on backing in mozilla.

Comment: Yes <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">  add this to your head tags it will reload the page

Comment: Not sure but it may work. Thanks and hope I helped you something on this. Cheers

Comment: So you problem solved and if you are satisfied you can vote me up/mark my answer. As topic now goes to this kind of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404038/reload-the-page-when-visited-by-clicking-back-button-in-firefox